# Finding moment of inertia of quadrant of an ellipse.

Tags: integration, conic-sections, classical-mechanics

Find the  moment of inertia of quadrant of an ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$ of mass $M$ about the z axis if density is proportional to $xy$.

I was applying this formula $$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{b^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})}} xy(x^2+y^2) dx dy$$ Is this the correct way or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right. Note that the density $\rho$ is just proportional to $xy$, so we can write $\rho=Cxy$. To find the value of $C$, you know that the total mass is $M$:
$$M=\int_0^a dx\int_0^\sqrt{b^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})} Cxy dy$$
So
$$C=\frac{M}{\int_0^a dx\int_0^\sqrt{b^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})} xy dy}$$
Then your moment of inertia $I$ is:
$$I=M\frac{\int_0^a dx\int_0^\sqrt{b^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})} xy(x^2+y^2) dy}{\int_0^a dx\int_0^\sqrt{b^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})} xy dy}$$